# Regression output - is it possible to calculate the Standard error of coefficient just with the coefficient and its p-value?

Tags: math, statistics, regression, linear-regression, least-squares

Is it possible to calculate the standard error of coefficient "beta hat 5" without the t-ratio or is is this not possible with the given data?

I would be very thankful if you could explain it just briefly and in the most easy way whether this is possible or not.

Thank you!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste your code rather than post pictures. Additionally, this is not a discussion forum, you may want to take a look at other Stack communities.

Comment: I am really sry Nicolas but I don't have a code regarding this task. It is an exam question and I am confused how to derive the solution for X5 without the t-stat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the value of the t-statistic from the p-value by doing an inverse lookup on your probability table. from there, you can just do `t/beta_hat`.